# ValueError while fine-tuning TensorFlow image classification model using BiLSTM

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

When I'm trying to fit my model, the following ValuError problem arise but I can't solve it at all.

Any help is welcome,

My model here:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size = (3, 3), input_shape = x.shape[1:], activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size = (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size = (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size = (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model=Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(model,input_shape=x.shape[1:]))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(32)))
#model.add(LSTM(32))
model.add(Dense(64,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(32,activation='relu'))
#model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(5, activation = 'softmax'))


    
    import time
    start = time.time()
    history = model.fit(
        training_ds,
        batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
        validation_data=val_ds,
        verbose=1,
        epochs=EPOCHS,
    )
    print("Total time: ", time.time() - start, "seconds")


ERRORS: 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-0047cb4ed2fd> in <module>()
      6     validation_data=val_ds,
      7     verbose=1,
----> 8     epochs=EPOCHS,
      9 )
     10 print("Total time: ", time.time() - start, "seconds")

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in autograph_handler(*args, **kwargs)
   1145           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
   1146             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
-> 1147               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
   1148             else:
   1149               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1021, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1010, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1000, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 859, in train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 214, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(f'Input {input_index} of layer "{layer_name}" '

    ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "sequential_7" (type Sequential).
    
    Input 0 of layer "bidirectional_16" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, 224, 224, 3)
    
    Call arguments received:
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), dtype=float32)
      • training=True
      • mask=None
```

It also gives warning as "WARNING:tensorflow:Layer lstm_17 will not use cuDNN kernels since it doesn't meet the criteria. It will use a generic GPU kernel as fallback when running on GPU." when I have defined BiLSTM model in colab.

Comment: _expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, 224, 224, 3)_ seems pretty clear to me, no?

Comment: Please add your model